# Mock is not effective after twisted deferred is returned

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, twisted

I am having trouble with mocking in twisted trial unit test. The function under test returns a deferred, and I return that deferred from the unit test. However, it seems like the patches that I have applied are reverted once I return the deferred, it doesn't wait until the deferred is resolved.

Please see the following example:

**schedule.py**

```
import time
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

class Schedule():
    def get_time(self):
        t = time.time()
        return task.deferLater(reactor, 2, lambda: t)

    def get_time_future(self):
        return task.deferLater(reactor, 2, lambda: time.time())
```

**schedule_test.py**

```
import mock
from twisted.trial import unittest
from schedule import Schedule

class ScheduleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('schedule.time')
    def test_get_time(self, mock_time):
        mock_time.time.return_value = 1450407660
        d = Schedule().get_time()
        d.addCallback(self.assertEqual, 1450407660)
        return d

    @mock.patch('schedule.time')
    def test_get_time_future(self, mock_time):
        mock_time.time.return_value = 1450407660
        d = Schedule().get_time_future()
        d.addCallback(self.assertEqual, 1450407660)
        return d
```

**And the output**

```
test_schedule
ScheduleTest
    test_get_time ...                                                      [OK]
    test_get_time_future ...                                             [FAIL]

===============================================================================
[FAIL]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/trial/_synctest.py", line 437, in assertEqual
    super(_Assertions, self).assertEqual(first, second, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 515, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 508, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
twisted.trial.unittest.FailTest: 1456370638.190432 != 1450407660

test_schedule.ScheduleTest.test_get_time_future
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 4.024s

FAILED (failures=1, successes=1)
```

Is there something wrong in the way that I am mocking `time` in the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed something wrong with the way you are mocking `time`.  The `mock` decorator sets up the patches on entry to the test function and then removes them on exit.  But, you're returning a `Deferred`, which means that the `time.time` callback runs well *after* the test function has exited.

If you just want to continue using a mock-like patching interface, you can use Twisted's [`TestCase.patch`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.trial.unittest.SynchronousTestCase.html#patch), which I believe will take `Deferreds` into account.

However, [mocking is a testing anti-pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xu5EhKVZdV8), and a much better way to deal with the passage of time is to use [the documented API for testing the passage of time](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/trial.html#testing-scheduling), [`twisted.internet.task.Clock`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.internet.task.Clock.html).

Comment: `time` is just an example, but its not always `time` that I want to mock. `TestCase.patch` really helped to resolve the issue. I had to patch it like `self.patch(sys.modules['schedule'], 'time', mock_time)`

Comment: @AjmalA you should put that as an answer, that's a good find.

Answer (score 1):

As [Glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13564/glyph) pointed out, using [`TestCase.patch`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.trial.unittest.SynchronousTestCase.html#patch) can help. The patch needs to be performed as shown below:

```
def test_get_time_future(self):
    mock_time = MagicMock()
    mock_time.time.return_value = 1450407660
    self.patch(sys.modules['schedule'], 'time', mock_time)
    d = Schedule().get_time_future()
    d.addCallback(self.assertEqual, 1450407660)
    return d
```

This test passes.